# Multiple profiles for TorBrowser, two TorBrowsers open at once?

Tags: mac

Is it possible on a Mac to set up multiple profiles for the TorBrowser, each with different preferences, and have two TorBrowsers open at once?

Comment: An interesting question, it's certainly possible under Linux but I'm unsure how this would play out on the Mac, given that all instances would share the same DataDirectory, configuration location and other cache locations (`~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/`), you'd likely need to change the path and I'm unsure on OSX where it pulls that information from, possible some configuration data in the `.app`/`.dmg` file itself? You'd need to change the settings so that it instead used a location like `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser2-Data/` and change some of the ports used.

Comment: tl;dr - this is a non-trivial task that'll need some knowledge of Tor Browser internals and OSX packaging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible,
It all depends on the torrc file in the folder or the tor browser,

If you just want different settings, and not run multiple profiles at the same time, you exchange the torrc file.

If you want to run different settings at the same time, copy the folder multiple times, and make sure that the settings TorDirectory and SocksPort are different.
You will also have to change the Socksport of the used proxy in the torbrowser.

Any questions? ask!

Comment: WHERE is the torrc file located? I don't have that.

Comment: ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/torrc

Comment: I can't make it work. I made a copy, called TorBrowser2.app but when I launch it it says "A copy of Tor Browser is already open. Only one copy of Tor Browser can be open at a time."